# Is my render time too long and file size too big?

Tags: blend-files, optimization

I have a .blend file that is 135 MB, it contains 3 scenes (only two of them contain objects. the third is for a future composite of the other two scenes).

I have about 40 objects in the other two scenes - at least half of them are  human-like rigged meshes. I also have 7 candles with large flames made of smoke domains.

I worry that my objects and/or materials are more complex than they need to be, making the file size larger than necessary and render times longer than necessary.

One frame takes 6:40 to render at 1080 w/ 200 samples in Cycles. Is this the file size and render time I should expect for a file like this, or should I strive for more economical models and materials?

One scene has about 117,000 verts, the other has about 290,000 verts.
I would upload the file, but (obviously) it's too big.

Comment: File size is certainly big-ish, but nothing to be concerned about, I'd say. Also file size doesn't necessarily translate linearly to render time or memory consumption, although they are certainly closely related. I'd say 6:40 for a 1080 render is a very good time. Depending on what you want to render, of course it may quickly become unpractical for very long animations. Anyway, hard to know without looking at some screenshots, but nothing there seems obscenely out of place.

Comment: Render time depends on the complexity of the scene, render settings and the resources available on your computer. Each scene is different but the only thing that is constant is that **rendering takes time**

Comment: Some related threads: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48340/how-long-will-a-10-second-youtube-intro-take-to-render-i-have-had-it-rendering/52096#52096 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48887/a-powerful-graphics-card-or-cloud-render-farm-which-is-more-effective/48892#48892 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49087/rendering-isnt-stressing-gpu/49088#49088 and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48149/render-settings-for-rendering-an-animation-with-fire-smoke-simulation

Comment: @Fletch, what are the specifications of your machine, that is, processor,  amount of RAM, type of video card, and amount of video memory? It is possible if you have a small machine, that your file might be too big for your Blender installation.

Comment: @brasshat my computer specs are below:                                   -System: OSX 10.11.6

-Blender version: 2.76

-Processor: 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7

-Memory: 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

-Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2048 MB (I render on the CPU b/c I usually get a memory error when I try GPU).

Comment: <big grin mode> @Fletch, well, unless when you run Blender, you have a large number of background applications, specs are not a problem, but I couldn't see your machine from where I sit, and for all I could tell, you were trying to run it on a machine with 2GB of memory.</big grin mode>